# Is del called on an object that doesn't complete init?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Will `__del__` be called if an object's `__init__` does not complete (such as by throwing an exception)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        raise

    def __del__(self):
        print "__del__ called"

try:
    test()
except:
    pass
```

Yes.

**Explanation:** `__del__` is called when the last reference to the object is removed. But if you do not catch the exception, `__del__` will not be called because the python still keeps a reference to the object in the stack, and it's kept until the program exits in order to print the traceback. If you catch and handle the exception, the object is deleted as soon as the all the information relating to the exception is discarded from the stack.

Of course, `__del__` is not guaranteed to run successfully if the program is about to quit, unless care is taken, and in some circumstances not even then -- see [`__del__` warning](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__).

**Addenum:** Cédrik Julien said in his answer (now amended): "*If `__new__` raised an exception, your object won't be created and `__del__` won't be called*". This is not always right. Here's an example where `__del__` is called even though the exception is raised in `__new__`:

```
class test():
    def __new__(cls):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        raise
        return obj

    def __del__(self):
        print "__del__ called"
```

So some exception occurred while we did some stuff to the `test` object `obj` before returning it. But since the object was already created, `__del__` is called. The lesson is: *in the `__del__` method, don't assume anything that was supposed to happen after `object.__new__()` has in fact happened*. Otherwise you could raise an exception trying to access a non-existing attribute or by relying on some other assumption that is not valid. The exception will be ignored, but whatever task `__del__` was supposed to accomplish will fail as well.

Comment: Wow, this is brilliantly insightful. It has the added bonus of making sense from the C perspective too. object=PyObject.

Answer (score 14):

Answer is **YES**.

As discussed [here](http://www.algorithm.co.il/blogs/programming/python-gotchas-1-__del__-is-not-the-opposite-of-__init__/) `__del__` is not the opposite of `__init__`, but merely the oppposite of `__new__`.

If `__new__` raise an exception before the object creation (in general before the superclass call), your object won't be created and `__del__` won't be called, otherwise, object is created and `__del__` will be called.

The `__init__` method is a late initializer, the real object constructor is the `__new__()` method.

Comment: That is true: `__del__` is called when an existing object is destroyed. `__init__` is called with an already existing object (the `self` argument), so even if it fails there is something to call `__del__` for.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: If your question is *Will `__del__()` be called at all?*, then the answer is: **Yes**.

If, OTOH, your qestion is *Will it be called immediately?*, then the answer is:

**No, not necessarily**:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            Child(self)
        except:
            pass

class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        parent.child = self
        raise
    def __del__(self):
        print 'Child.__del__()'

p = Parent()
print 'hu?'
print p.child
print 'wha?'
```

Output:

```
hu?
<__main__.Child object at 0x7ff4674c>
wha?
Child.__del__()
```

`Child.__del__()` isn't called here when `Child.__init__()` fails, but when `p` is garbage collected, which is when the program ends.

Answer (score 1):

I second *lazyrs*' answer. However, I'd like to stress the point about the **last reference**.

If you pass `self` around to other objects (e.g. when registering callbacks) before the exception is raised, your object will still be alive, i.e. `__del__` is not called:

```
>>> keeprefs = []
>>> class X(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         keeprefs.append(self)
...         raise Exception()
...     def foobar(self):
...         print("this could be a zombie foobar")
... 
>>> x = X()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
Exception
>>> keeprefs
[<__main__.X object at 0x7f9e2630bc50>]
>>> keeprefs[0].foobar()
this could be a zombie foobar
```

In real life `keeprefs` could be, for instance, a framework where you register callback methods for some events. So when your exception is raised, the framework does not recognize this and happily calls methods of your apparently never created object.

@pillmuncher's answers also illustrates the *last reference* problem, but I think the framework/callback example is more startling.